# Wordpress Custom user Display Page

Tags: wordpress

First I want to preface this with the page was working this morning and I left the page open and came back to the information of the user not displaying at all

This page is a custom written authors display page. Anyone who is a contributor of the site is listed here with a bio, Avitar and nickname, can someone please tell me what I am missing because I can't see what has been deleted.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Display Authors
*/

// Get all users order by amount of posts
$allUsers = get_users('orderby=post_count&order=DESC');

$users = array();

// Remove subscribers from the list as they won't write any articles 
foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
{
if(in_array( 'contributor', $currentUser->roles ))
{
$users[] = $currentUser;
} 
}
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="content-area" role="main">
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div class="authors">
<?php foreach($users as $user) { ?>
<div class="page-author author-<?php echo ($curauth->ID & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even'); ?>">
        <div class="author-avatar">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $curauth->user_email, '200' ); ?>
    </div>
        <div class="author-info">
            <h2 class="author-name"><?php echo $curauth->first_name . ' ' .            $curauth->last_name; ?></h2>
            <h3 class="author-username"><?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <p class="author-descrption"><?php echo   get_user_meta($curauth->ID,'description', true); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
 ?>
 </div>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

UPDATE:

So here is an update in my code, and still no luck, all the user information on the page remains empty. So its not showing the Name, Nickname, Bio...nothing

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Display Authors
*/

// Get all users order by amount of posts
$allUsers = get_users('orderby=post_count&order=DESC');

$users = array();
// Remove subscribers from the list as they won't write any articles
foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
{
if(in_array( 'contributor', $currentUser->roles ))
{
$users[] = $currentUser;
}
}
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="content-area" role="main">
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div class="authors">
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
<div class="page-author author-<?php echo ($curauth->ID & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even'); ?>">
        <div class="author-avatar">
            <?php echo get_avatar( $curauth->user_email, '200' ); ?>
    </div>
        <div class="author-info">
            <h2 class="author-name"><?php echo $curauth->first_name . ' ' .  $curauth->last_name; ?></h2>
            <h3 class="author-username"><?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <p class="author-descrption"><?php echo get_user_meta($curauth->ID, 'description', true); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>    
</div>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: If nothing is shown at all, it is probably a php error. Try to turn on error_reporting and post the displayed error.

Comment: I should specify more clearly, none of the author information is appearing, the css styling and the rest of the page shows up...

Comment: http://baliblinds.wpengine.com/?page_id=7

Comment: @MeghanDonnelly that page redirects to `wp-login.php`

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I can't actually send the link off network. I'm hoping someone can still help I will upload a screen shot - Sorry apparently i'm not rated high enough to submit and image....

Comment: I would try print_r($allUser) and print_r($users), just to make sure that there are any users.

Comment: I am looking at the users admin page as we speak and there are 6